A girl blackmails a guy but loses the tape
I saw this movie in 2004 in a hotel. It could have been made before that year.
Basically, a guy is seduced by a girl for the sake of obtaining a tape showing him being seduced.
She threatens to show the tape to his wife if he does not pay some money..
The girl loses the tape at some point (maybe her boyfriend destroys it after watching his girlfriend "having good time with another man"), but she continues to pretend to have it and even receives the money in return for a fake tape, but the guy doesn't know it's fake because he destroys it immediately.
I remember another scene where a guy gets knocked down by a sack full of oranges, and he is killed afterwards. The guy with the sack is later seen making juice with the remainder of the oranges.
Color, English.

Pretty sure it's 100 Mile Rule from 2002. From Amazon:

A somewhat happily married man is seduced by a blackmailing hottie named Monica (played by Maria Bello) while in LA for a salesmanship seminar. Our hero is one of three salesman who finds himself the subject of extortion when it turns out that his fling with Monica was videotaped. Can he come up with the thirty grand he'll need to keep his wife from getting the tape? 

Here's the orange-sack beating:



